# Relay HTTP request through other servers and back

Tags: http, cloud

I have 6 Ubuntu cloud servers, which of one acts as a main Django deployment with an intranet and cronjobs.

For the cronjobs I request data from different data-sources, that I want to go through the other 5 cloud servers.

My question is; can I send a HTTP request to each of the Relay Servers, so that they will literally push that request (clone?) through to the requested Data Source and give back the response data?

[image: Relay Request]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using the relays?  Load on the main server is likely to be higher than the load on one unbalanced relay server.  Simplest approach to using the relay servers would be round robin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a forward HTTP proxy. Install something like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and configure the main server to use a proxy for outgoing requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you give a small example for my situation? How would I configure my main server. Can it also be load balanced, letting the main serve choose the least burdened Relay server?